# Differences in Binding between Silverlight and WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I was looking for code samples of the `ListPicker` control In Windows Phone 7 and I ran into this one
(http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/f397b9/using-listpicker-in-windows-phone-7/)

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="lpkItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="lpkFullItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
.
.
.
<toolkit:ListPicker FullModeItemTemplate="{Binding lpkFullItemTemplate}"
            Grid.Row="5" ItemTemplate="{Binding lpkItemTemplate}"
            x:Name="lpkCountry"/>
```

In this example the `ListPicker DataTemplates` are defined inside the `PhoneApplicationPage.Resources` dictionnary, and the properties `FullModeItemTemplate` and `ItemTemplate` are set using the `{Binding}` extension, I have a little background in WPF so I wasn't expecting the code to run properly but when I tried it it worked just fine, so I tried an equivalent example in WPF but did not work

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Name="btnComic">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{Binding btnComic}" Content="Test"/>
</Grid>
```

Is binding in silverlight and WPF so different to the point that the same syntax works in one platform but not in the other? or I'm just missing something?

Comment: Unless the ListPicker's DataContext is set to something that contains these properties it doesn't make any sense. Unless the `{Binding}` implementation in WP also means `{StaticResource}`???

Comment: Also, `x:Name` is not valid for resources (in WPF), it should be `x:Key`?? I'm confused.

Comment: Yeah, that is crazy -- there is no way that code runs as written.

Comment: I tried the code and it realy works, I locked in the msdn to see if there is an explanation to that but couldn't find anything useful

Comment: @HighCore I was confused too, but not anymore I also missed that the binding could have failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF and WP Silverlight are somewhat different, but the bindings work in more or less the same way.  The code at the link is gibberish.  (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16925866/1001985) for a correct example.)

What is probably happening is that the "FullModeItemTemplate" and "ItemTemplate" bindings are failing (check your Output window in VS to confirm).  Notice that the `DataTemplates` are also nonsense (the items are strings, not objects with a "Country" property).  The code probably runs because the ListPicker will display the items as strings without the item templates set.

Comment: ... how could I miss that? LOL

Comment: Well I did miss that too, I can't test it right now but I think you are totally right.